# Where does `logger` save messages to on macOS?

Tags: logs, macos, logger

I'm writing a shell script that utilizes the Linux [`logger`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) to log output. Based on that documentation, I believe that the logging is sent to `/var/log/syslog` on Linux which would be `var/logs/system.log` on Mac.

Here's a simplified version of my script for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$RANDOM
logger "testing: $n is a random number."
```

When running it and then viewing `system.log` I don't see any of my messages. However, I *do* see the messages in the Mac OS `Console.app` if I search for "testing":

[image: Console.app showing logger event]

My question is: where on the Mac file system are these logs stored? They must be somewhere, but I can't seem to find them. They're definitely not in `/var/log/system.log`.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052538/1032785

Comment: Thank you. For others visiting this question, the answer appears to be: Apple broke this functionality in Sierra. The workaround is writing the log to your own log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@joranm's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052538/1032785), `logger` does not send to `system.log` as of macOS Sierra. Instead, I've decided to just output to my own log file using [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirect_(computing)):

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$RANDOM
echo "testing: $n is a random number." >> ./random_log
```

Keep in mind that you can use `>>` to *append to* the file and `>` to *overwrite* it.